# Why I am getting 2 rows with same data as a result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using sql join for refining some result but i am not getting my result as expected.
My query was

```
select order_detail.*, product.img1, product.added_by, 
        product.fa,product.name, commition.commission 
from order_detail,product,commition 
where order_detail.order_id='ODN314746M38' 
and product.id=order_detail.product_id 
and product.added_by='1' 
and commition.subcat=product.subcat
```

As a result i should get only the one row but I am getting 2 rows with same result

My actual data table is

[image]

But I am getting 2 rows back as a result like

[image]

why this is happening?
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your query doesn't have any `join`

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass I am a beginner Can you help me out how to tackle this

Comment: Which field connects `order_detail` to `product` and which field connects with `commition`? I suppose it's `product_id` between `order_detail` and `product`.

Comment: Please post data and code as text not images. This will help others to help you.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass `product_id` in `order_detail` connects `order_detail` to `product ` and ` subcat` in `product` connects with  `commition`

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass The join conditions are in the `WHERE` clause. `product.id=order_detail.product_id` and `commition.subcat=product.subcat`.

Comment: You're getting 2 results because there's either 2 `order_detail` rows with this `order_id` or 2 `comition` rows with this `subcat`.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass Editing capability is expected to be used to fix minor issues like wording, typos, formatting. We don't use it to change the technical content.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass Read the bullet points below that.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass @Barmar Thanks to both of you after running timothy's code when i was getting error i read barmer's comment  and i found that really there are duplicate values in `commition table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be 2 rows in `comition` with a matching `subcat`. Add `comition.id` to the SELECT list to see this.

You will need to refine the relationship with the `comition` table so you only return the appropriate row for this order. Without knowing more about your table structure I can't be more specific.

It's also helpful to use ANSI `JOIN` as in the other answer. This makes it easier to see how all the tables relate to each other, and often makes it clearer where you're missing a condition.